# Vuex, watch and lifecycle hooks in Vue.js 3 with SSR

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3

I know that a `watch` runs before the `beforeUpdate` lifecycle event occurs. However, I have things in the `watch` which **must** complete before the virtual-DOM is re-rendered/updated.

My `watch`is like this:

```
setup () {
     watch(() => $route.params.ProductID, async () => {
     // Update Vuex here with ProductID data and then do a whole bunch of stuff here that must complete before updating the DOM
     },
    {
        deep: true,
        immediate: true
    })

onBeforeUpdate(() => {
    // Use stuff that was created in watch above
})
}
```

This code is not only run by the client, but also the server for SSR.

I have tried to test if `watch` will complete all tasks first before `onBeforeUpdate()` runs like this:

```
setup() {
    async function testWatch(){
          setTimeout(function(){ return console.log("I am watcher timeout"); }, 3000);}
    
     setup () {
             watch(() => $route.params.ProductID, async () => {
             await testWatch();
             },
            {
                deep: true,
                immediate: true
            })
        
        onBeforeUpdate(() => {
            console.log("I am onBeforeUpdate hook");
        })
        }
}
```

If I run the above I get the output of:

```
I am onBeforeUpdate hook
```

then 3 seconds later..

```
I am watcher timeout
```

How can I ensure that the code within the `watch` will execute before anything else in the component? I need this to happen so that the correct data is available to the component before it renders.

Answer (score 1):

*How can I ensure that the code within the watch will execute before anything else in the component?*

You can't - it is not possible.

Your best bet is to move the async code to route guards as described in the docs - [Fetching Data Before Navigation](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation)

Problem with the approach is (or can be - sometimes) that the fetching code (`getPost` function in the example) cannot be a method on the component and (logically) has no access to `this`

Comment: The other problem with this method is server-side rendering. If I use `beforeEnter` or `onBeforeRouteUpdate` with `vue-router` and preload the data store (Vuex) before the component is loaded, the data gets overwritten if a different product route is accessed inbetween. So if you go to `route/product/1`, load the data store with `ProductID=1`, but then someone else requests `route/product/2` you will get back the data for `ProductID=2` instead of `ProductID=1`. It is very annoying.

Comment: Well that sounds like you are not doing the SSR right. Each SSR request should have its own router/Vuex instance - [Avoid Stateful Singletons](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/ssr/structure.html#avoid-stateful-singletons). What you describe sound like your router is shared between all active requests...

Answer (score 0):

I solve this sort of thing by creating a data property 'loading' that gets set to false when loading is done.

Then use a v-if to only render stuff when 'loading' is false.

Comment: Some of this data is used by other plugins and then injected into to the page e.g. `<head>` tags. A `v-if` in the HTML of the component doesn't help in this case